# Can anybody help me with the installation of RStudio in Ubuntu 23.10 mantic?

Tags: software-installation, r, rstudio

i've been trying to install RStudio in the pc (Ubuntu 23.10 mantic) through many tutorials but i've not been able to. Huge thanks for your time.

Comment: please [edit] your question to indicate what you have tried and any error messages received. Little point in trying to second guess what you have tried only to be told "tried that, didn't work". Read [ask] for further guidance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: the most common error is this